# Alternar href de tag "a" ao clicar em outros elementos

Tags: jquery

Tenho dois botões de seleção de pagamento onde ao selecionar um botão, um terceiro botão para finalizar o pagamento tem seu href trocado, de acordo com a opção escolhida.

Demostração no codepen: http://codepen.io/flashpremium/pen/xbzzry

Comment: Qual é sua dúvida ou problema? não ficou muito claro.

Comment: @GêBender seria que a url de um botão fosse alterada de acordo com a seleção da div, exemplificando: Ao selecionar a Div 1 o link do botão 1 continua o mesmo ao selecionar a div 2 o link do botão 2 tem a sua url alterada.

Comment: O terceiro botão não está lá ou está comentado. Deixe ele visível, com a url para ficar mais facil.

Comment: @GêBender pronto, botão adicionado.

Comment: Você quer no caso, que ao clicar no botão "Pagseguro" o href dele mude? Não entendi direito.

Comment: @haykou exatamente, de acordo com a seleção seja ele paypal ou pagseguro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, informe os links dos botões em um atributo HTML, como o data-rel, por exemplo

**HTML**

```
<div data-rel="http://www.link1.com.br" class="menu_button">
    <i class="fa fa-paypal"></i> PayPal
</div>

<div data-rel="http://www.link2.com.br" class="menu_button">
    <i class="fa fa-google-wallet"></i>  PagSeguro
</div>

<a class="btn-checkout" href="">Pagar </a>
```

Agora na ação do click, você só pricisa passar o valor do data-rel clicado para o href do terceiro botão.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu_button').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
      $(".btn-checkout").attr("href", $(this).attr("data-rel"));
    });
});
```

E pronto, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Realmente é isso, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Uma sugestão seria adicionar um atributo data no botão do menu e alterar o atributo `href` e o texto do botão de comprar conforme o botão clicado, veja o exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.menu_button').click(function() {
          $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
          //Altera o atributo href do link
          $('.btn-checkout').attr('href',$(this).data('url'));
          //Altera o texto conforme o botão clicado
          $('.btn-checkout span').text($(this).text());
     });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.off-canvas-cart {
  width: 250px;
  height: 1080px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: right;
}

.menu_button {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 250ms;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #868696; background-size: 60%; background-position: 50% 50%; width: 180px; height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #6c6c7d;
}

.menu_button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: 250ms;

}

.menu_button:active {
    color: #ccc;
}

.menu_button.selected {
    background: #43434a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 .2em #279ad1;
  transition: 250ms;


}



.menu_button.selected:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  content: '';
  background: #279ad1;
}

.btn-checkout {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #019df4;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;  
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #017cc1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 250ms;
}

.btn-checkout:hover {
  background: #2FAEF5;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-checkout:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 #017cc1;
  background: #2FAEF5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="off-canvas-cart">

<div class="menu_button selected" data-url="http://www.paypal.com">
  <i class="fa fa-paypal"></i>
  PayPal
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu_button" data-url="http://www.pagseguro.com.br">
    <i class="fa fa-google-wallet"></i>  
  PagSeguro
  </div>
      <a class="btn-checkout" href="http://www.paypal.com">Pagar com <span>PayPal</span></a> 

</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.